# Prevent MicroSD from writing to C drive

Tags: filesystems

This may not be the wise choice, but i have installed portable apps onto a MicroSD card to conserve space on my drive. Is it possible to prevent these programs to write to the C drive and still have the function to save files from the C drive to the SD card?

Comment: Please advise which OS, and which version of that OS, you are using. Click on `edit` above and to the left and add that important information to your original post.

Answer (score 2):

No, assuming you're on Windows.  Unless you're willing to do a lot of workarounds.  Programs each have their own directories which they will attempt to write settings, logs, temporary files, and other changes.  You would need to track each and every folder written to, and put in a folder alias back to the SD card.  Some programs let you adjust the directories that they use for temp files, but most don't.

Years ago, "InstallWatch Pro" was useful for figuring out what folders were being written to.  There are modern equivalents, but I haven't used any of them.

I would suggest getting a larger hard drive; they are cheap and much more reliable for extended use than the SD card.

Comment: There are very few programs that are intended to be run from removable storage, so getting anything not specifically written to be "stand alone" to not write to the registry, AppData, or a couple other places isn't going to be easy, like you said.